# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; when creating table

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm a complete noob with MySQL and I could use as much detail as possible.

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''D5F9F589C9C' at line 1371

---

```
-- Dumping data for table wcrp_gameserver.accountnotes: ~3,090 rows (approximately)
```

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `accountnotes` DISABLE KEYS */;

```
INSERT INTO `accountnotes` (`noteid`, `accountid`, `setby`, `seton`, `note`) VALUES
```

^ That's the query and this is line 1371:

```
(9678, 38742, 30, '2015-06-11 20:36:31', 'Kicked: Don\'t abuse /report'),
```

Comment: Can you show us the part of the file where "D5F9F589C9C" appears?

Comment: Your error message and code disagree. Where is `'D5F9...` applied

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following SQL statement

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype
```

If you wish to add, drop or modify a column.

You don't need to use ALTER TABLE if you just want to INSERT a row.

That said, with the information given, it seems you just need to delete the comment

```
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE accountnotes DISABLE KEYS */;
```

And I will make sure columns **noteid, accountid, setby, seton, note** exist in accountnotes table and values are set according to their datatype.